# Avoiding circularity when testing elements in lxml

Tags: python, lxml, getelementsbytagname

I have this problem, I am processing some tables using lxml- the original source files are in mhtml format, they are excel files.  I am needing to find the rows that contain the header elements 'th' elements.  I want to use the header elements but need the rows they came from to make sure I process everything in order.

So what I have been doing is finding all of the th elements and then from those using the e.getparent() function to get the row (since a th is a child of a row).  But I end up having to pull the th elements twice, once to find them and get the rows and then again to take them out of the rows to parse the data I am looking for.
This can't be the best way to do this so I am wondering if there is something I am missing.

Here is my code

```
from lxml import html
theString=unicode(open('c:\\secexcel\\1314054-R20110331-C20101231-F60-SEQ132.xls').read(),'UTF-8','replace')
theTree=html.fromstring(theString)
tables=[e for e in theTree.iter() if e.tag=='table']
for table in tables :
    headerCells=[e for e in table.iter() if e.tag=='th']
    headerRows=[]
    for headerCell in headerCells:
        if headerCell.getparent().tag=='tr':
            if headerCell.getparent() not in headerRows:
                headerRows.append(headerCell.getparent())
    for headerRow in headerRows:
        newHeaderCells=[e for e in headerRow.iter() if e.tag=='th']
        #Now I will extract some data and attributes from the th elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over all `tr` tags, and just move on to the next one when you find no `th` inside.

EDIT. This is how:

```
from lxml import html
theString=unicode(open('c:\\secexcel\\1314054-R20110331-C20101231-F60-SEQ132.xls').read(),'UTF-8','replace')
theTree=html.fromstring(theString)
for table in theTree.iter('table'):
    for row in table.findall('tr'):
        headerCells = list(row.findall('th'))
        if headerCells:
            #extract data from row and headerCells
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for much more pythonic than what I was doing

Answer (score 1):

To avoid doing it twice, you could use a dictionary keyed by row element and accumulate all the header cells from a given row into an assocated list, which can be done in a single pass through the table's elements. To keep rows ordered by when they were seen you can use an `OrderedDict` from the built-in `collections` module. This would allow something along these lines to be written:

```
from lxml import html
from collections import OrderedDict
f='c:\\secexcel\\1314054-R20110331-C20101231-F60-SEQ132.xls'
theString=unicode(open(f).read(),'UTF-8','replace')
theTree=html.fromstring(theString)
tables=[e for e in theTree.iter() if e.tag=='table']
for table in tables:
    headerRowDict=OrderedDict()
    for e in table.iter():
        if e.tag=='th':
            headerRowDict.setdefault(e.getparent(), []).append(e)
    for headerRow in headerRowDict:
        for headerRowCell in headerRow:
            # extract data and attributes from the <th> element from the row...
```